# Fechas como columnas en postgresql (pivot)

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo una tabla llamada *ingresos_leche_detalle* la cual almacena el **id_proveedor**, **fecha** y **cantidad** de leche ingresada, al hacer la siguiente consulta obtengo la sumatoria por dia de leche de cada proveedor

```
select p.nombre as proveedor, ic.fecha, sum(id.cantidad) as cantidad
from ingresos_leche_detalle id, ingresos_leche_cabecera ic, contactos p 
where id.id_proveedor=p.id and  id.id_cabecera=ic.id and ic.fecha between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31' 
group by p.nombre, ic.fecha
order by p.nombre
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero necesito que la tabla me quede asi:

```
proveedor         | 2020-08-01 | 2020-08-01 | 2020-08-01 | ... | 2020-08-26 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ANA VERGARA       |   40       |    38      |    40      | ... |   95       |
ANTONIO BARRETO   |   35       |    34      |    35      | ... |   NULL     |
CARLOS PRIETO     |   34       |    39      |    37      | ... |   NULL     |
.
.
.
```

se deben tener en cuenta que las fechas pueden variar, por ejemplo del 2 al 23 del mes y algunos dias un proveedor puede no haber llevado leche.

espero haber sido claro y gracias.

Comment: cuál es el motivo de que necesites la tabla final? para mostrarla así? Si ese es el caso en código tendrás que transformarla a ese formato. Ya que postgresql no hace lo que pides. Mi recomendación sería que hagas el group por fecha y luego por nombre, y así será un poco mas fácil formar esa vista.

Comment: ¿Cuantas fechas necesitás mostrara horizontalmente?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho necesito que los rangos sean dinamicos,  desde 1 o dos dias, hasta 60 o 365 dias

Comment: @nax es para un reporte que quiero mostrar en una jtable

Comment: Tiene que ser una consulta o puede ser una función en plpgsql?

Comment: Tambien puede ser una funcion, no hay problema, lo que me interesa es que me retorne las tuplas para usarlas en java

Comment: Aqui se dio una respuesta similar a la que creo que quieres llegar, con SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808189/setting-column-values-as-column-names-in-the-sql-query-result

Comment: Creo que este sitio web te puede ayudar con lo que buscas.
[Link de la web](https://ed.team/blog/consultas-avanzadas-en-postgres-con-tablas-de-referencia-cruzada-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo de tu Tabla

[image: Tabla Ejemplo 1]

Con esta consulta podrías mostrarlo en el formato que quieres.

[image: Consulta Ejemplo 2]

Pero ya que la cantidad de tus fechas es variable tendrías que hacer algo así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SET @lista = ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(CASE fecha WHEN ''', fecha, ''' THEN cantidad END) AS ''', fecha, '''' ) ) AS lista FROM prueba );

SET @QUERY = CONCAT( 'SELECT proveedor, ', @lista, ' FROM prueba GROUP BY   proveedor ' );
PREPARE my_query 
FROM
    @QUERY;
EXECUTE my_query;
```