# Poner como columna campo fecha y desplegar sus detalles

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Tengo la siguiente tabla de datos que saqué con una consulta donde junté 2 consultas en una, el campo `Fecha de pago` es de la segunda consulta, donde muestro la fracción del año que le corresponde

`Tabla 1`

```
Fracción Importación    Valor Comercial Importación Fecha de pago   Fraccion    Valor Comercial
85045099                4185787.29                  2015            85045099    307032.000000
84819099                419688356.99                2015            84819099    398684.000000
84212199                11248672.39                 2015            84212199    24028.000000
83082001                149868.94                   2015            83082001    146.000000
73202001                30344893.96                 2016            73202001    425610.000000
48081001                8201767.45                  2016            48081001    29.000000
85364103                100958.22                   2017            85364103    341099.000000
84831003                6971766.61                  2017            84831003    3074.000000
```

El objetivo es organizar la tabla de forma que muestre por año las fracciones que le corresponden junto con su `Valor Comercial`, en este caso el campo `Fecha de pago` es el que quiero poner como columna y por cada `Fecha de pago` muestre su `Fraccion` y su `Valor Comercial`, cabe mencionar que no sé cuantos años pueda tener `Fecha de pago`, pueden ser más años, en este caso es dinámico y debería verse así como lo siguiente

`Tabla 2`

```
Fracción Importación    Valor Comercial Importación 2015        Valor Comercial 2016        Valor Comercial     2017        Valor Comer
85045099                4185787.29                  85045099    307032.000000   73202001    425610.000000       85364103    341099.000000   
84819099                419688356.99                84819099    398684.000000   48081001    29.000000           84831003    3074.000000
84212199                11248672.39                 84212199    24028.000000    null        null                null        null
83082001                149868.94                   83082001    146.000000      null        null                null        null
```

El contenido de la tabla 1 lo almaceno en una tabla temporal llamada `#reportTable` y una vez almacenado, lo que hago es un `pivot` para poner el campo de `Fecha de pago` como columna pero al parecer no me esta resultando porque el pivot necesita una función de agregación pero yo no quiero la función de agregación, simplemente quiero poner su detalle o su `Fraccion` por año y este es el resultado que me arroja el query:

```
Fracción Importación    Valor Comercial Importación 2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021
85045099                4185787.29      85045099    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85049001                137380.00       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85049007                21384.12        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85049099                352339.37       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85051101                9849.26         NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85051999                1858452.35      NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85059099                74472.00        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85068001                1682954.82      NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85068004                821767.92       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85072003                606438.02       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85072004                65658.00        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Este el `pivot` que estoy utilizando

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max), @query as nvarchar(max)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Fecha de pago]) 
                from #reportTable
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select [Fracción Importación], [Valor Comercial Importación], ' + @cols + ' 
 from 
 (
    select [Fracción Importación], [Valor Comercial Importación], [Fecha de pago], [Fraccion], [Valor Comercial] 
    from #reportTable
 ) x
 pivot
 (
    max([Fraccion])
    for [Fecha de pago] in ('+ @cols +')
 ) u
 '
exec sp_executesql @query;

/* Lo que regresa si lo meto en un PRINT
select [Fracción Importación], [Valor Comercial Importación], [2015],[2016],[2017],[2018],[2019],[2020],[2021] 
from #reportTable 
pivot
(
  max([Fraccion])
  for [Fecha de pago] in ([2015],[2016],[2017],[2018],[2019],[2020],[2021])
) u 
*/
```

Referencia:
[Fechas como columnas en postgresql (pivot)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386127/fechas-como-columnas-en-postgresql-pivot)

Al parecer siento que el `pivot` no es factible para hacer esto porque estoy intentando poner varios detalles de un solo dato, en este caso por año en un dato horizontal así que mi duda es, hay alguna otra forma de hacer esto? encontré algunas referencias de este escenario pero todos sacaban un promedio, sumaban o contaban un campo para mostrarlo en el `pivot` pero al parecer no puedes poner un `pivot` sin una función de agregación, a menos que haya otra forma de implementar esto.

Agradezco de antemano

Comment: Existen otras formas más eficientes y versátiles que pivot. Pero es un poco confuso porque no sé como defines los valores comerciales en varios años si las fracciones solo se muestran en un año.

Comment: @LuisCazares si, los valores comerciales son una sumatoria de su valor comercial por cada fracción

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que la pregunta es interesante, pero en mi criterio, parte de un planteamiento erróneo.

El problema es que los lenguajes `SQL`, no tienen un orden y tal cual lo planteas, parece entenderse que los valores para esas fracciones y valores comerciales, parten del orden de la fila en la que están.

Voy a mostrarte una posible solución, que quizá requiera unos cuantos retoques, porque no está del todo claro, además tiene bastante complejidad, pero si manejas los pivots dinámicos yo diría que es bastante asumible.

Notas: la tabla temporal la he convertido en una tabla, con estos tipos de datos.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[reportTable](
    [Fraccion_importacion] [int] NULL,
    [valor_comercial_importacion] [money] NULL,
    [fecha_de_pago] [smallint] NULL,
    [Fraccion] [int] NULL,
    [valor_comercial] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Lleno los datos.

```
INSERT [dbo].[reportTable] 
([Fraccion_importacion], [valor_comercial_importacion], [fecha_de_pago], [Fraccion], [valor_comercial]) 
VALUES 
(85045099, 4185787.2900, 2015, 85045099, 307032),
(84819099, 419688356.9900, 2015, 84819099, 398684),
(84212199, 11248672.3900, 2015, 84212199, 24028),
(83082001, 149868.9400, 2015, 83082001, 146),
(73202001, 30344893.9600, 2016, 73202001, 425610),
(48081001, 8201767.4500, 2016, 48081001, 29),
(85364103, 100958.2200, 2017, 85364103, 341099),
(84831003, 6971766.6100, 2017, 84831003, 3074);
```

Lo primero, vamos a utilizar la función `row_number()` para numerar las filas por `fecha_de_pago`, particionando por esta columna.

```
;With c as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by fecha_de_pago order by fecha_De_pago) as rn
    from dbo.reportTable
) select * from c;
```

[image: Imagen1]

Según lo que yo he entendido, de los datos, cualquier valor que esté en rn=1 tienen que visibilizarse en la fila 1 y así sucesivamente.

Para poder hacer esto, vamos a agruparlos utilizando la función de ventana `lag`

```
;With c as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by fecha_de_pago order by fecha_De_pago) as rn
    from dbo.reportTable
) 
, grp as 
(
    select *, case when lag(rn,1) over(partition by fecha_De_pago order by fecha_de_pago) IS null then 1 else 0 end as grp
    from c 
) Select * from grp;
```

[image: Res 2]

Ahora si aplicamos un sum a cada uno de los valores de grp, ya tenemos el inicio y final de cada grupo.

```
;With c as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by fecha_de_pago order by fecha_De_pago) as rn
    from dbo.reportTable
) 
, grp as 
(
    select *, case when lag(rn,1) over(partition by fecha_De_pago order by fecha_de_pago) IS null then 1 else 0 end as grp
    from c 
), c2 as (
    select *, SUM(grp) over(ORDER BY fecha_De_pago ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grupo 
    from grp 
)
Select * from c2
```

[image: Table3]

Para `pivotar` vamos a utilizar el operador `apply`, que nos resuelva las columnas correspondientes a `fracción` y `valor_comercial` que requiere cada grupo. Este es otro punto "especial", porque he tratado dos conjuntos. Aunque el hecho de que sea dinámico, en un escenario mejor definido, igual se podría hacer una función table-inline..... o dar un máximo de conjuntos, x y no mostrar sus resultados, o .....

```
With c as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by fecha_de_pago order by fecha_De_pago) as rn
    from dbo.reportTable
) 
, grp as 
(
    select *, case when lag(rn,1) over(partition by fecha_De_pago order by fecha_de_pago) IS null then 1 else 0 end as grp
    from c 
), c2 as (
    select *, SUM(grp) over(ORDER BY fecha_De_pago ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grupo 
    from grp 
)
select c2.Fraccion_importacion
     , c2.valor_comercial_importacion
     , c2.Fraccion as [An1]
     , CAST(c2.valor_comercial AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS valor_comercial
     , fn.Fraccion_importacion as [An2]
     , CAST(fn.valor_comercial AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS valor_comercial
     , fn2.Fraccion_importacion as [An3]
     , CAST(fn2.valor_comercial AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS valor_comercial
from c2 
    outer apply (
        select * 
            from c2 b where b.rn = c2.rn
                and b.grupo-1 = c2.grupo 
                
        ) fn
    outer apply (
        select * 
                from c2 b1 where b1.rn = c2.rn
                    and b1.grupo-2 = c2.grupo 
        ) fn2

where c2.grupo = 1;
```

[image: Res 4]

Ya se parece bastante a los datos a regresar, donde solo extraemos del conjunto c2 las filas del grupo 1.

Evidentemente, aquí debería de ser el grupo que más filas tuviera, y por eso mismo el resto de conjuntos `fn` deberían de comportarse en consecuencia. Como es para una query dinámica, esto se podría realizar de un modo parecido a lo siguiente.

Cambiar los literales y consumir la query de un modo dinámico, lo he construido con un replace sobre una variable tabla de valores

```
Declare @table table (id int, col varchar(10), fecha_de_pago VARCHAR(10))
Insert into @table (id,col, fecha_de_pago)
values
(1,'[An1]',null),
(2,'[An2]',null),
(3,'[An3]',null);


with c as (
    Select  fecha_de_pago, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by fecha_de_pago) as rn
        from 
        (   select distinct fecha_de_pago from dbo.reportTable
        ) as d
    )
Update t set t.fecha_de_pago = QUOTENAME(CAST( c.fecha_de_pago AS varchar(10)))
From @table t inner join c on t.id = c.rn;

select * from @table;
```

[image: Table5]

Todo junto sería:

```
Declare @table table (id int, col varchar(10), fecha_de_pago VARCHAR(10))
Insert into @table (id,col, fecha_de_pago)
values
(1,'[An1]',null),
(2,'[An2]',null),
(3,'[An3]',null);

with c as (
    Select  fecha_de_pago, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by fecha_de_pago) as rn
        from 
        (   select distinct fecha_de_pago from dbo.reportTable
        ) as d
    )
Update t set t.fecha_de_pago = QUOTENAME(CAST( c.fecha_de_pago AS varchar(10)))
From @table t inner join c on t.id = c.rn;

Declare @query nvarchar(max);
set @query = N'
;With c as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by fecha_de_pago order by fecha_De_pago) as rn
    from dbo.reportTable
), grp as 
(
    select *, case when lag(rn,1) over(partition by fecha_De_pago order by fecha_de_pago) IS null then 1 else 0 end as grp
    from c 
), c2 as (
    select *, SUM(grp) over(ORDER BY fecha_De_pago ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grupo 
    from grp 
)
select c2.Fraccion_importacion
     , c2.valor_comercial_importacion
     , c2.Fraccion as [An1]
     , CAST(c2.valor_comercial AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS valor_comercial
     , fn.Fraccion_importacion as [An2]
     , CAST(fn.valor_comercial AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS valor_comercial
     , fn2.Fraccion_importacion as [An3]
     , CAST(fn2.valor_comercial AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS valor_comercial
from c2 
    outer apply (
        select * 
            from c2 b where b.rn = c2.rn
                and b.grupo-1 = c2.grupo 
                
        ) fn
    outer apply (
        select * 
                from c2 b1 where b1.rn = c2.rn
                    and b1.grupo-2 = c2.grupo 
        ) fn2

where c2.grupo = 1;'

SELECT @QUERY=REPLACE(@QUERY,T.col, T.fecha_de_pago)
fROM @TABLE T;

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY
```

[image: Resultado]

**Importante**: No se puede predecir el orden de las filas, aunque te funcione siempre, cualquier conjunto que no tenga un order by no tiene porque retornar las filas en un orden. O dicho de otro modo, te las devuelve 1000 veces de una manera, y la 1001 puede ser de otra.

Esta respuesta es solo un planteamiento de ayuda, no pretende resolver la pregunta, porque hay muchas incógnitas en el aire.

Parte de ella se basa en que será para un reporte, por tanto el número de columnas, aunque dinámico, es bastante posible, que no sobrepase un número de años, pequeño.

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte, enserio fue de gran ayuda, saludos

Comment: donde aplicas el `apply` para pivotear, le agregas las columnas `An1, An2, An3`como si solo fueran solo esas, en este caso yo le agregué más pero el query resulto demasiado lento, el `apply ` hace que se haga lento?

Comment: Es posible. En el escenario indicabas `#reportTable `,si esta contiene muchas filas. Posibles mejoras, a lo mejor indizar o crear una estadística sobre la columna fecha_de_pago o reconducir los outer apply a left join. Pero todo esto son conjeturas, porque no se sabe el plan de ejecución que se está aplicando.